# Use of unresolved identifier 'DefaultConflictHandlers'

Tags: swift, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am following the [Build a Mobile App With Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mobile/build-sync/) tutorial MongoDB provides but running into an error when configuring the sync on a particular collection. This is my code:

```
todoCollection.sync.configure(
    conflictHandler: DefaultConflictHandlers.remoteWins.resolveConflict,
    changeEventDelegate: { documentId, event in
        if !event.hasUncommittedWrites {
            // you can add code here to update your app's UI or
            // perform other operations based on a document change.
        }
}, errorListener: self.on)
```

These are my imports:

```
import MongoSwift
import StitchCore
import StitchRemoteMongoDBService
```

And for clarity's sake, here is the error:
[image]

I have some theories, like a separate import required or my XCode indexing is just broken, but no success so far.

**Edit**: I am using `pod 'StitchSDK', '~> 5.0.0'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed that pod and found you need to add

```
import StitchCoreRemoteMongoDBService
```

And `DefaultConflictHandlers` is renamed with `DefaultConflictHandler`

So after importing your code will be:

```
todoCollection.sync.configure(
    conflictHandler: DefaultConflictHandler.remoteWins.resolveConflict,
    changeEventDelegate: { documentId, event in
        if !event.hasUncommittedWrites {
            // you can add code here to update your app's UI or
            // perform other operations based on a document change.
        }
}, errorListener: self.on)
```

Comment: yeah import removed the error, however the new method call looks like this:
`DefaultConflictHandler<TodoItem>.remoteWins()` Everything is running smoothly now, thanks.